# How to draw ringing bell in HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw a bell icon on an HTML `canvas` and need animation effects on the image like a bell ringing. I haven't been able to find a good way to resolve this. Like draw a bell icon and only do vibration on the lower part of the bell. Can someone give me a hint and show an example? Here's what I've done so far:

```js
var x = 20;
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

var mapSprite = new Image();
mapSprite.src = "https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20190411/ourmid/pngtree-vector-bell-icon-png-image_927119.jpg";

function drawIt() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(drawIt);


  c.globalAlpha = 0.07;
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // c.fillStyle = "white"; 
  c.fillRect(x, 10, 80, 100);
  c.stroke();
  c.globalAlpha = 1;

  c.drawImage(mapSprite, x, 10, 80, 100);


  if (x == 20)
    x -= 3
  else
    x += 1;
}

//window.requestAnimationFrame(drawIt);
drawIt();
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the bell dome from the clapper and animate them separately (or draw the clapper your self with a circle).

You can either only move the clapper or add different animations to each of them: while the clapper would describe an arc trajectory, bouncing from side to side of the dome, the dome would rotate from the top center.

Here's a simplified version of this:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 

const width = canvas.width = document.body.offsetWidth;
const height = canvas.height = document.body.offsetHeight;

const  bellImg = new Image();

bellImg.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc7Ih.png";

const clapperRadius = 25;
const lineWidth = 10;

let progress = 0.5;
let progressDelta = 0.05;

function tick() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height); 
  
  ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;

  ctx.beginPath();
  
  const circleLeftMin = width / 2 - bellImg.width / 2 + clapperRadius + lineWidth;
  const circleLeftMax = width / 2 + bellImg.width / 2 - clapperRadius - lineWidth;
  const circleLeft = Math.min(Math.max(circleLeftMin + (circleLeftMax - circleLeftMin) * progress, circleLeftMin), circleLeftMax);
  
  progress += progressDelta
  
  if (progress >= 1 || progress <= 0) {
    progressDelta = -progressDelta
  }
  
  ctx.arc(
    circleLeft,
    height / 2 + bellImg.height / 2,
    clapperRadius,
    0,
    2 * Math.PI,
  );
  
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.drawImage(
    bellImg,
    width / 2 - bellImg.width / 2,
    height / 2 - bellImg.height / 2
  );
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame(tick); 
} 

bellImg.onload = () => {
  tick();
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height:100%;
}

#canvas {
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height :100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Question, is there any easy way to handle the size of both the bell and the clapper at a same time? I need to use this bell inside of small area within canvas but seems to be do a more calculation for clapper if i change the bell image size. Any idea about that?

Comment: You might want to look into the `canvas` `scale()` method, but either way, you'll probably need some work to adjust everything.